# Closed form expressions for series solutions of D.E's

Tags: power-series, closed-form

So, I was reading about power series solutions to differential equations and the author stressed how one should not bother trying to identify the final series solution with any closed form expression.

Now, he didn't really state that such a closed form **will not exist** for some series, he just insisted not to bother with trying to find one.

My question then is, is it so that some power series just DO NOT have closed form expressions no matter how hard we try to find or is it that theoretically we could find a complicated closed form expression to every series if we try hard enough?

EDIT: By closed form I mean some combination of elementary functions.

Comment: It is probably due to the fact that most of the "well known" odes with solutions of a closed form can be recognized without going through a power series expansion. Therefore, if you require a power series expansion then a closed form solution probably doesn't exist. Just a theory.

Comment: You should first define "closed form". For instance, does hypergeometric series admit a tautological closed form in terms of hypergeometric function, or this should be considered as a notation?

Comment: Okay, I have updated the original post.